# Access password blocked sheet - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, view, passwords

The code below restricts access by hiding a sheet unless a password is entered. If it is entered correctly, the sheet can be viewed from the individual tabs. However, it won't let me view and then edit the sheet.

Can this be adjusted to allow the user to enter a password and then view and edit the sheet?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub

Public ViewAccess As Boolean       'In restricted sheet's activate event
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
If ViewAccess = False Then
Me.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Response = Application.InputBox("Password", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
    If Response = "123" Then
        Me.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ViewAccess = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just turn on/off [Worksheet Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect). ...actually, you might consider using the `Worksheet.Protection` password parameter after making the sheet visible. That would also prevent someone from just making the sheet visible.  Also, I'd use `xlSheetveryhidden` instead of `xlSheetVisible`. That makes the worksheet unable to be unhidden unless you use VBA.

Comment: @BruceWayne, could you add this into the code so I cant accept the answer. I'm having the same issue. I need to be able to view and edit the sheet after the correct password has been entered.

Comment: That's almost a new question/task altogether. I suggest first [searching around](https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+add+worksheet+protection+password) first.

Comment: It's not protecting a sheet, it's restricting access. I've updated the question in case this wasn't clear the first time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code will help you. When a user will select a sheet with name `HiddenSheet` it will ask for password. If password is correct then it will allow for editing data otherwise will go to previous sheet automatically, You have to change `HiddenSheet` for your sheet name.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheetName As String

MySheetName = "HiddenSheet" 'The sheed which I want to hide.

If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
    response = Application.InputBox("Password", "Enter Password", "", Type:=2)

        If response = "123456" Then 'Unhide Password.
            Application.Sheets(MySheetName).Visible = True
            Application.Sheets(MySheetName).Select
        End If
End If

Application.Sheets(MySheetName).Visible = True

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

***Code snipped:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Haran24HR. This is exactly what I'm after. Could I incorporate a few sheets with the same password?

Comment: Glad to know! You can do that.